# Telerik RadGridView collection custom editor

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have a `RadGridView` with binding to an `ObservableCollection` of `TestType`.

`TestType` contains 3 members:

```
string TestString;
Int TestInt;
List<string> TestCollection;
```

I added 3 record to the `ObservableCollection`.

The binding works, and I can see the records.

When i'm trying to edit the table, I can't edit the `TestList` member cell.

In winforms property grid i added an `EditorAttribute` like that:

```
[Editor typeof(CollectionUITypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)].
```

And than, the member will be editable with a custom editor (in the property grid).

Is there anyway to make custom editor works at cell editting?

Answer (score 3):

You need the CellEditTemplate: [Setting CellTemplate and CellEditTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/celltemplate-and-celledittemplate.html)

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TestTypeList}">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TestString}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TestInt}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TestCollection}">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    // Here give a template for the "TestCollection" when it is not in editing.
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    // Here give a template for the "TestCollection" when it is in editing.
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>           
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

When you Bind a **Simple type** to the DataMemberBinding, Telerik give you a default "CellTemplate" and a default "CellEditTemplate" for the binded type.

But if you Bind a **Complex type** to the DataMemberBinding, Telerik doesn't know how to template it, so you need to give it your own Data Template for the normal state (CellTemplate) and for the Edit state (CellEditTemplate).